# How to handle OutOfMemoryException until it does not throw again?

Tags: c#, arrays, exception, int, out-of-memory

I got to know the maximum object size in C# is 2GB. Also there is a memory limit for each particular PC and either it is 32 or 64 bit.

In my application I need an array of integers as big as possible. So what I need is to take care of `OutOFMemoryException` until the biggest possible array can be made!

I end up with the code below:

```
private int[] AllIntegers()
{
    int[] all;
    int divider = 2;

    try
    {
        all = new int[int.MaxValue];
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryException)
    {
        all = new int[int.MaxValue / divider];
    }
    //Probably will fail again. how to efficently loop the catch again

    for (int i = 0; i < all.Length; i++)
    {
        all[i] = i;
    }

    return all;
}
```

the code will also fail, what I am looking for is a proper way of looping untill the array can be made!

Comment: What is your scenario? Why do you need this? Do you really need to hold such large structure in memory? Why not use a dynamically growing list?

Comment: Even if you succeed doing that, you won't be able to use it. Once you fill up all the memory allowed to you by the OS with your array, you will not have any free memory to allocate any more variables.

Comment: @Darin I am just exprimenting the limits. no particular scenario at the moment. What you mean is using `List<int>` ? what will be the limit for that?

Comment: @Svarog You are right, but probably for testing I will reduce the array size just to leave some memory free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** I do not like the idea of this, since I think it's wrong to hold such a large amount of data
(and an array of all integers?)

But, here's what you're looking for:

```
    static int[] AllIntegers()
    {
        int iSize = int.MaxValue;
        int[] all;
        int divider = 2;

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                all = new int[iSize];
                break;
            }
            catch (OutOfMemoryException)
            {
                iSize = iSize/divider ;
            }
        }

        //Probably will fail again. how to efficently loop the catch again

        for (int i = 0; i < all.Length; i++)
        {
            all[i] = i;
        }

        return all;
    }
```

**EDIT2:**
Maybe elaborate us with what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Did you test this? OOM is difficult to catch.

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes I have, the size I got is 134217727
probably not the maximum size, but thats what I got.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`System.Runtime.MemoryFailPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.memoryfailpoint.aspx) to check if sufficient resources are available before attempting to allocate the object.

Comment: A `MemoryFailPoint` instance still throws, albeit a different exception type. It doesn't try again with decreasing memory amounts, as the questioner wants. A loop would still be necessary.

Comment: Yes a loop is need but at least the exception is safely catchable.

Answer (score 1):

It is always not a good idea to hold such big array in memory.

Can't you split your big array into small ones, and based on range to load appropriate array?